# Exercise n 2.10 Billingsley- probability and measures - third edition

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I'm attempting to solve this exercise but I don't where to start.
Plese help me :)
[Exercise n. 2.10 billingsley](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otyMq.jpg)

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

From my limited experience, these problems are usually solved by construction and/or by coming up with some kind of a contradiction.

For Question 1):

1. Assume the contrary, that there exist $w,w'$ such that for all $A \in \mathscr{A}$, either $w\in A,w'\in A$ or $w \notin A,w'\notin A$.
2. We construct the following set: $\mathscr{B}=\{S - \{w,w'\}, S \cup \{w,w'\}| S \subset \Omega\}$. Show that $\mathscr A \subset \mathscr B$.
3. Show that $\mathscr B$ is a $\sigma-$algebra and conclude (Hint for the conclusion: You can, for example, start by looking at the definition of $\sigma(\mathscr A)$).

For Question 2) observe the fact that all you need to show is that all singletons are in $\sigma( \mathscr A )$ (why?). Let us look at the family of sets $(U_{w,w'})_{w, w' \in \Omega,w \neq w' }$ defined such that $w \in U_{w,w'}$ and $w'\notin U_{w,w'}$.

1. Justify the existence of such a family in $\sigma(\mathscr A )$ (Reminder: If $A \in \mathscr A$ then $A^c \in \sigma(\mathscr A)$).
2. Set $V_w = \bigcap_{w'\in \Omega-\{w\} } U_{w,w'}$. What does $V_w$ equal to? Why does $V_w \in \sigma(\mathscr A)$?
3. Conclude.

For the last question, take for example $\Omega= \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathscr A = \mathscr T(\mathbb R)$ the standard topology. This topology is Hausdorff (T2). But the family of Borel sets $\mathscr B (\mathbb R) = \sigma (\mathscr T(\mathbb R))$ does not contain all subsets of $\mathbb R$. Even less so, it is a family with the cardinality of "only" $\mathbb R$.

Feel free to ask in the comments in case any part of the answer is not clear.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hints!

Comment: I don't have a mathematical background so I don't know what is a topology, can you explain the third answer in another way?
Thank you again!

Comment: @GiadaSpaccapanico Unfortunately, I am fairly sure that the solution requires a somewhat nontrivial example, like the one we want to consider. The topology of $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathscr{T}$ is the collection of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. the family of all sets $O$ such that $\forall x \in A, \exists$ a nontrivial interval  $I_x \subset A$  such that $x \in I_x$). Now for each pair of points $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ we can find two disjoint open intervals (which are open sets), each containing one of the points. To see this, choose $I_a = \{x ; |x-a|<|a-b|/2 \}$, $I_b = \{x ; |x-b|<|a-b|/2 \}$.

Comment: However $\sigma \mathscr T = \mathscr B (\mathbb{R})$ is not equal to the family of all subsets of $\mathbb R$